# Failed to start MariaDB 10.3 database server

Tags: mariadb, rhel

Unable to start mariadb.service. I'm getting following error while starting mariadb.service.

```
[root@localhost bggb]# systemctl start  mariadb.service
        Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
        See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here is the status of mariadb.service

```
[root@localhost bggb]# systemctl status mariadb.service
            ● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3 database server
               Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
               Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-07-12 16:56:03 IST; 59s ago
                 Docs: man:mysqld(8)
                       https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
              Process: 6260 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited>
              Process: 6221 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCC>
              Process: 6196 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
             Main PID: 6260 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
               Status: "MariaDB server is down"
            
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain mysqld[6260]: 2021-07-12 16:56:03 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init funct>
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain mysqld[6260]: 2021-07-12 16:56:03 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registrati>
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain mysqld[6260]: 2021-07-12 16:56:03 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disa>
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain mysqld[6260]: 2021-07-12 16:56:03 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plu>
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain mysqld[6260]: 2021-07-12 16:56:03 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported stor>
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain mysqld[6260]: 2021-07-12 16:56:03 0 [ERROR] Aborting
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain mysqld[6260]: Warning: Memory not freed: 520
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, statu>
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
            Jul 12 16:56:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3 database server.
```

Hear is the output of journalctl -xe for more information as requested. Configuration is done first time.

```
[root@localhost bggb]# journalctl -xe
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: == Stack trace for context 0x55df8c69>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #0   7ffd7797b5d0 b   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #1   7ffd7797b680 b   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #2   55df8cc77d30 i   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #3   7ffd7797c610 b   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain gnome-shell[2874]: Object .Gjs_CapsLockWarning (0x55df8d192040), has>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #4   55df8cc77ca0 i   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #5   55df8cc77c20 i   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: == Stack trace for context 0x55df8c69>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #0   7ffd7797b5d0 b   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #1   7ffd7797b680 b   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #2   55df8cc77d30 i   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #3   7ffd7797c610 b   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #4   55df8cc77ca0 i   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2874]: #5   55df8cc77c20 i   resource:///org>
Jul 12 17:45:52 localhost.localdomain gnome-shell[2874]: Object .Gjs_CapsLockWarning (0x55df8d192040), has>
Jul 12 17:45:53 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[1115]: <info>  [1626092153.0272] agent-manager: agent>
Jul 12 17:46:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- The unit fprintd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
```

Comment: And the `journalctl -xe` output?

Comment: Also you should check the end of the lines. There is a `>` char indicating that the line is truncated. Maybe use the keyboard arrow keys to scroll to the right. There seems to be important information there.

Comment: mysql does not have aria table engine, therefore your question is not applicable to mysql, just to mariadb.

Comment: @yunzen edited for -xe

Comment: @Shadow ok but have installed mysql also...

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: It is not relevant what other products you have installed. What matters is what product is in scope for your particular question.

Comment: better than the `journalctl -xe` output that systemd always recommends is service specific information on the service `journalctl -n 50 u mariadb.service`.

Comment: seems, MySQL is not installed properly or you don't have enough privileges on datadir.

Answer (score 6):

Renaming the log files and starting MySQL might be an option to fix this.

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0.bak 

mv /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1.bak

systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: No-one should do this. Ever. At least you put renames as opposed to just `rm`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the MariaDB datadir isn't writable. Check it is owned by the  `mysql` user along with the subdirectories:

```
 chown -R mysql: /var/lib/mysql
```

If you have moved your datadir to somewhere under `/home`, in addition to changing the permission above (with path corrected) disable the protection of [ProtectHome](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/#configuring-access-to-home-directories) in systemd with:

Run: `systemctl edit mariadb.service` and include the following in the editor before saving and exiting:

```
 [Service]
 ProtectHome=false
```

Then restart the service:

```
systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

If you have changed the datadir from the default /var/lib/mysql

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/mariadb/data(/.*)?"
restorecon -Rv /var/lib/mysql
```

It could be also that if your datadir is a freshly created filesystem it needs the right selinux labels:

```
restorecon -Rv /var/lib/mysql
```

For further information see the MariaDB [selinux article Knowledge Base](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/selinux/).